# Firebase email/password authentication in electron

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I did firebase authentication with email/password in my electron app, and it works, but only on first page. When I go to second page, I'm no longer signed in. Because I'm new to elecetron.js and firebase as well I used this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWS0ocfszmE.

login.js

```
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var emailField = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var passwordField = document.getElementById('password').value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailField, passwordField).then(function() {
        document.location.href = 'mainPage.html';
        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);

    }).catch(function(error) {
        if (error != null) {
            console.log(error.message);
            alertify.error(error.message);
            return;
        }
    });
```

secondpage.js

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
```

I expected the output in console with user that I signed in, but get null.

Comment: Can you please share how you did authentication? I am unable to find any resources on internet. The video u shared is currently private.

Comment: @VikramRayavarapu I've ended up wrapping Angular in that Electron app. Then I used the solution for web app from documentation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth). Finally to get a logged in user I used onAuthStateChanged, mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507035/11617396).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on each new page Firebase Authentication will check whether the user's sign-in token is still valid. Since this may take some time (and require calling a server), this happens asynchronously. And by the time your `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)` runs, the process hasn't completed yet.

That's why you'll want to [use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to detect the authentication state of the user:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```